# NoScript: is it possible to temporarily allow JS from some domain only on a selected site?

Tags: firefox, noscript

For instance, when I come to site superuser.com, I would like to temporarily allow `ajax.googleapis.com` - but just on this site, not anywhere else.

I know this can be done permanently ([using ABE](https://superuser.com/questions/587367/noscript-how-to-allow-script-on-one-domain-only)), but I would like these permissions to be temporary. Can this be done?