# How to enable only some particular scripts from a specific domain with NoScript in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, privacy, noscript

As far as we all can see StackExchange sites  have started to require (seems that I can't even accept an answer without it) scripts from googleapis.com. Which is [said](http://www.donottrackplus.com/trackers/googleapis.com.php) to be "a widget company that is part of a network of sites, cookies, and other technologies used to track you" which I don't want to allow. So, I'd like to allow some particular scripts needed by StackExchange to function without whitelisting the whole domain. Is there a way to reach this?

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/587367/noscript-how-to-allow-script-on-one-domain-only/587893#587893

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allow a script to run on a single domain with NoScript?](https://superuser.com/questions/587367/how-to-allow-a-script-to-run-on-a-single-domain-with-noscript)

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve more granular whitelisting in NoScript by using custom rules in ABE (*NoScript Options|Advanced|ABE*) that allow remote scripts only to be executed on sites you trust.

```
Site .googleapis.com
# Allow googleapis.com for SE sites
Accept from .stackexchange.com serverfault.com stackoverflow.com superuser.com 
# Deny from all others
Deny
```

*Note: As ABE's rule work independently from NoScript, you will need to whitelist the site in NoScript **before** being able to filter it with ABE.*

See [NoScript FAQ 8.10 (Can I use ABE to fine-tune NoScript's permissions?)](http://noscript.net/faq#qa8_10) and the [ABE documentation](http://noscript.net/abe/) for more details.