# Allow 'block objects' from a specific site

Tags: firefox, noscript

I want to allow "blocked objects", including fonts, for certain sites with the NoScript FireFox plugin.

I understand [why NoScript blocks fonts](https://hackademix.net/2010/03/24/why-noscript-blocks-web-fonts/), but for a few trusted websites I want to allow them nonetheless.

I read [how to allow script from one domain only](https://superuser.com/questions/587367/noscript-how-to-allow-script-on-one-domain-only) and [how to enable some particular scripts](https://superuser.com/questions/616447/how-to-enable-only-some-particular-scripts-from-a-specific-domain-with-noscript) besides the [ABE manual](http://noscript.net/abe/abe_rules.pdf). But I cannot make it work. Here a few ABE rules I've tried for Toggl:

```
Site .gstatic.com .bootstrapcdn.com
Accept from .toggl.com

Site fonts.gstatic.com maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com
Accept INCLUSION(SCRIPT, OBJ, CSS) from .toggl.com

Site fonts.gstatic.com maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com
Accept from .toggl.com
```

Neither of these rule sets will allow font inclusion for Toggl, however. Do you see where I'm going wrong?

(NoScript 2.6.9.6rc3 on FireFox 34.0.5)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the [noscript site](https://noscript.net/features) states:

> For example, setting the `noscript.allowedMimeRegExp` preference value
>   to
>
> - `FRAME@https?://somesite\.com`
> - `FONT@https?://some-other-site\.com`
> - `WebGL@https://www\.khronos\.org`
>
> will permanently allow any
>   FRAME/IFRAME load from somesite.com, web fonts from
>   some-other-site.com and WebGL 3D content from `https://www.khronos.org`.

I don't think the ABE can do it. One hacky way to enable the font only for a particular site/domain is to use Vimperator/Pentadactyl and change the MimeRegExp setting automatically on a LocationChange event. To revert the setting when leaving the page, you could use this simple function (got it from [Anekos](https://github.com/vimpr/vimperator-rc/blob/1b28c2e0eb2d6e6a639b6b8046db1fce16a50e1a/anekos/.vimperatorrc.js#L149)) in .vimperatorrc that uses an expression with a negative lookahead:

```
js <<EOM
function add_AutoCommand(URI, onEnter, onLeave) {
    let entered = false;
    autocommands.add('LocationChange', '(?!' + URI + ')', function () {
      if (entered) {
        entered = false;
        onLeave();
      }
    });
    autocommands.add('LocationChange', URI, function () {
        onEnter();
        entered = true;
    });
}
add_AutoCommand(https?://allow-font-on-this-site\.com, 
    :set! noscript.allowedMimeRegExp="FONT@https?://some-other-site\.com", 
    :set! noscript.allowedMimeRegExp=" "
);
EOM
```

I haven't tested this but I will.

**EDIT**: it should be

```
add_AutoCommand('https?:\/\/allow-font-on-this-site\\.com.*', 
    function(){options.setPref("noscript.allowedMimeRegExp",
        "FONT@http://fonts.gstatic.com")}, 
    function(){options.setPref("noscript.allowedMimeRegExp", 
        "")}
);
```

...but noscript doesn't pick up on the preference unless the page is reloaded, so either manually reload or use `tabs.reload(config.browser.mCurrentTab, false);`

It seems that you should set a boolean and a timeout to prevent LocationChange to execute (thus, looping) the reload again. Perhaps another autocmd on the PageLoadPre event might be used for the boolean. This is getting quite ugly I know. Sorry.

*ps. a more useful application of simple URL-based pref switching is obviously changing the download directory.*

**EDIT** (2017): With [uBlock Origin](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock) you can specifically target certain types of html objects, files or behaviors.

Both dynamic as well as static rules specify that origins are allowed for a domain/url. I've been using this for a few years now. Types include *font* as well as *inline-script*, *stylesheet*, *image*, *object*, *script*, *xmlhttprequest*, *sub_frame*, *media*, *websocket*, *popunder* and *popup*.

example rules:

```
* * 3p block
no-remote-fonts: * true
no-remote-fonts: allow-font-on-this-site.com false
allow-font-on-this-site.com font-cdn.org noop
```

which mean:

1. block third party request from any page to anywhere
2. block third party fonts on any page from anywhere
3. re-enable third party fonts on a page on the domain *allow-font-on-this-site.com* from anywhere
4. optionally re-enable request on our page to origins on the domain font-cdn.org

With *noop* ('no operation') we still apply static rule filtering (commonly defined in distributed rules known as ad-blocking or malvertising lists).

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer and the time you put into it.